# Is there a python function for RBF Ridge Regression?

Tags: python, regression, non-linear-regression

I want to fit a model with RBF regression with regularization (ridge regression) in python. Are there python pre built functions?

Comment: Certainly not in the standard library, and if you want something that's not in the standard library your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Chris. This sort of question is off topic even when things are in the standard library, in my opinion.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, very probably. But in this case it _certainly_ is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Scikit-Learn, see [`sklearn.linear_model.Ridge`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)

> This model solves a regression model where the loss function is the
>   linear least squares function and regularization is given by the
>   l2-norm. Also known as Ridge Regression or Tikhonov regularization.
>   This estimator has built-in support for multi-variate regression
>   (i.e., when y is a 2d-array of shape [n_samples, n_targets]).